# How do I correctly render elements in my template shown as [Object Object]?

Tags: arrays, meteor, bootstrap-modal

How do I correctly rendar elements in my template shown as [Object Object]?

I call the `categorySlideInMenu` which is template in subject, by passing some parameters via the Modal.show() function as such: `Modal.show('categorySlideInMenu', {Name: cats});`

But before I call the Modal.show() function, I print out the **cats** array, as such:

`console.log ("Show: "+cats);`

Below are the results:

```
Show: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

The expected results are: `Shoes: 1, Clothes: 1, Electronics: 1`

This is because the cats array values are added via `cats.push({Item: item, checked: "1"})`

The result are to be shown in my "**categorySlideInMenu**" template after I run `Modal.show('categorySlideInMenu', {Name: cats});`.

Below find the code in my "**categorySlideInMenu**" template:

```
 <form id= "categoryForm"> 

   {{#each Name}}

         <div class="checkbox-inline botomSpace">
         <label><input type="checkbox" name="Category" value="{{this}}" >{{this}} </label>
         </div>

            {{#with cats}}

                <div class="checkbox-inline botomSpace">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="Category" value="{{this}}" checked> {{this}} </label>
            </div>

            {{/with}}



   {{/each}}

</form>
```

The above renders as three checkboxes each with an **[object Object]**
The expected results are three checkboxes each with an Item value, eg Shoes, Clothes and Electronics.

In an attempt to get it to render correctly I have tried `{{this.Item}}` and `{{Item}}` which all dont render anything at all.

Help! Kindly point out what am doing wrong.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`{{this.Item}}` does not work because you have an array of objects, so it's not defined. What you need instead is `this[0].Item`, so use a helper to return the cats object you are looking for.

If item's an object, then you need to render `{{this.item.name}}` for example (with `this` being a cat object, not an array).

In the `console.log`, you can do `console.log("show",cats)` or `console.log("show",...cats)` which will spread out the array into objects.

Update:

```
   {{#each Name}}

         <div class="checkbox-inline botomSpace">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="Category" value="{{this.Item.name}}" >{{this.Item.name}} </label>
         </div>

         <div class="checkbox-inline botomSpace">
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="Category" value="{{this.checked}}" checked> {{this.checked}} </label>
         </div>
   {{/each}}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Am not sure how I'd use a helper to return the cats objects. I tried by adding a helper function called: Name with return cat;. Now I don't get any [ object Object]now it's totally empty.

Comment: Will update this with an example later when I am not on my phone. Try passing cats as a parameter to the helper. And why do you have two checkbox implementations in the same each loop?

Comment: okay, just remember that this is a template that I want invoked by Modal.show(). To answer your question, the second checkbox should show if the cats object is checked, the check box should also appear as checked. I hope am clear?

Comment: I don't think you need the `{{with}}` inside the `{{each}}`. I think every instance of the `{{each}}` is already wrapped in a `{{wtih}}`.

Comment: I created a helper for the "categorySlideInMenu" template. In the helper I am able to `console.log("show",...cats)` which successfully spreads out the array and its contents into objects. I end with `return cats;` at the end of the helper function, but I am still unable to get the template to render the desired Items. To check if the helper is working, I tried changing the return from `return cats;` to `return db.CollectionName.find({}).fetch();` this worked well, but the items I am interested in are in `return cats;`. Any idea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: So in order to help you, I need to understand the difference between the output of `console.log(cats)` and `console.log(db.CollectionName.find({}).fetch();)`? I know `.fetch` returns an array of objects, and so is `cats`. So its probably a structure difference. Also can you show the new code for how you are using the helper and the helper itself?